# Is there a way to specify custom arguments to docker run command executing inside Azure functions

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-docker

I'm trying to deploy a custom image to an azure function and I have a requirement of modifying `/etc/hosts` file inside the container.

I've tried giving `--add-host` argument at the docker build stage but it doesn't help. And as it is an azure function, It'll run the docker run command by itself without manual intervention.

So, just wanted to know if there's a possibility of adding `--add-host` argument to docker run command through Azure function's configuration.

Comment: Setting up [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/) seems like it'd be a better approach.

Comment: Using Azure DNS for container instances is fine, but in this case function app spins the container by itself.

Comment: What is the purpose that you need to modify the file `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: The server doesn't recognize the hostname which is being passed as it is private and hence, for it to recognise, I'm trying to modify container's `/etc/hosts` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's impossible to add `--add-host` argument to the docker run command. That's the function runtime and it's deployed by the Azure platform. You cannot change any parameters in it.

If you want to modify the `/etc/hosts` file, there are two ways to do it as I know. One is that change it directly when you create the custom image. Another one is that enable the SSH server in the custom image and then change the `/etc/hosts` file when the function runs well from your custom image via the SSH connection.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the response.
I've tried doing it from within the image using CMD but the functionality is being modified as I have other RUN commands within the dockerfile. And, using the second approach it is working perfectly fine if I modify it from the SSH console of the functionapp

Comment: @SpandanaSoma If you have other RUN commands, you can do it at the end of the Dockerfile. And those are two possible ways ad I know. If the answer works for you, please accept it.

Comment: @SpandanaSoma Any more questions? Do you solve the problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu can you give example for the RUN commands approach. I am afraid I could not follow it properly